# AngularJS - Control ng-show through custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

----UPDATE, see below for original question----

I'm isolating the problem, and right now something here is messing with the ng-show, I can't control it directly.

VIEW

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="vm.errorNoExistePDF" data-translate="webclientesApp.policy.terms.errorPDF">
    Ocurrio un problema al tratar de recuperar el archivo.
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
 function PolicyController(Principal, Policy, $locale, $rootScope) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.polizas = null;
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;
```

DIRECTIVE

```
function tablaPolizas(Principal, $locale, $state, $rootScope, $http, $window, $stateParams) {
var directive = {

    templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla-polizas/tabla-polizas.html',
    link: linkFn,

    ...

function linkFn($scope, $element, $attrs) {

vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;

...

angular.element('#tabla-polizas').on('click', '#terms', function() {
                    var table = angular.element('#tabla-polizas').DataTable();

        $http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/'+datos, {
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    })
                    .success(function(data, response) {

                        ...

                    })
                    .error (function(data){
                        console.log("ERROR");
                        vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;
                    });
            });
```

----ORIGINAL QUESTION----

I'm trying to show an alert message with a ng-show that calls a scope in the controller whose value (boolean) changes through a custom directive.

VIEW

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="vm.errorNoExistePDF" data-translate="webclientesApp.policy.terms.errorPDF">
    Ocurrio un problema al tratar de recuperar el archivo.
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
 function PolicyController(Principal, Policy, $locale, $rootScope) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.polizas = null;
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;
```

DIRECTIVE

```
 function tablaPolizas(Principal, $locale, $state, $rootScope, $http, $window, $stateParams) {
    var directive = {

        templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla-polizas/tabla-polizas.html',
        link: linkFn,
       restrict: "E",
       controller: function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;
        },
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }

    return directive;

    function linkFn($scope, $element, $attrs) {

        var vm = this;
        var urlIdioma = null;
        var table = angular.element('#tabla-polizas');
        var dataRow = null;
        var id = null;
        var estaFila = null;
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;

        ...

        $http.get('/webclientes/api/policies/getPlanFile/'+datos, {
                            responseType: 'blob'
                        })
                        .success(function(data, response) {

                            var file = new Blob([data], {
                                type: 'application/pdf'
                            });
                            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                            if ($window.navigator && $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                                    $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file);
                            }else
                            $window.open(fileURL);
                        })
                        .error (function(data){
                            console.log("ERROR");
                            vm.errorNoExistePDF = true;
                        });
                });
```

What should be happening here is that when user clicks into a Datatable button, if there's a bad response from server, ng-show (vm.errorNoExistePDF) should trigger and show the message, but I'm failing to understand the logic of linking directives and controllers.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: how are you using this directive?

Comment: Hi tanmay, this directive implements a datatable which reacts to the language key and regenerates with the token selected (out of 3 possible languages).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related with the scope, if you use controllerAs syntax with a directive and you want to bind the outer scope to the directive's controller's scope you should use `bindToController: true`.

So you can try using this directive definition:

```
var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/tabla-polizas/tabla-polizas.html',
    link: linkFn,
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        errorNoExistePDF: '@'
    },
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function(){
        var vm = this;
        vm.errorNoExistePDF = false;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
}
```

Comment: Hello Manuel, thanks for the help. I'm trying this, and ng-show still does not answer. The value of the vm variable changes in the directive, but doesn't seem to bounce on the controller (it keeps as 'false' all the time).

Comment: Try using two-way data binding `errorNoExistePDF: '=' ` instead of `errorNoExistePDF: '@' ` and if it does not work maybe you have to add a `watcher` in the linking function and use `errorNoExistePDF: '=' `

Comment: Hi again Manuel. I tried your approach, but got a `Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'errorNoExistePDF' used with directive 'tablaPolizas' is non-assignable!`.

Comment: Ups sorry, I think the error is because you are not defining the attribute friends in the DOM, Angular cannot create the bi-directional binding and throws the error, you can use the question character to make the attribute optional and to avoid the error: `errorNoExistePDF: '=?'`. Maybe it should be nice if you create a plunkr with the code in order to see what's happening there